# Javascript function post and call php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

In html I have several buttons which are automatically made for each object in the database with a particular status. Each button gets its own id.

```
echo '<Button id="button'.$counter.'" onClick="clickedbutton('.$counter.', '.$row['OrderID'].')" >'."<center>".$row['OrderID']."<br>"."</center>".'</Button>';
```

The button calls the javascript function clickedbutton and gives it the number of the button and the orderid of that button.

```
function clickedbutton(buttonid,orderid){
buttonid = "button" + buttonid;

}
```

This function loads in the number of the button and makes it button0, button1 etc. The orderid is also succesfully passed through. Now in the function I want to call an external php script, but also orderid must be passed through to the script.

```
<?php
    //connect to database
    include_once('mysql_connect.php');

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());

    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "update orders set OrderStatus = 'In Progress' where OrderID = '" + orderid + "'";

    mysql_close();
?>
```

I know about the mysqli protection and all, I will adjust that later. Now I want to focus on the question above, how to call and pass through the variable orderid to the phpscript.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**EDIT 2018**

Yeah, I am still alive. You can use the `fetch` API instead of `jQuery`. It is widely supported except (guess who?...) IE 11 and below but there is a polyfill for that. Enjoy modern coding.

[Support for fetch API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch)

**OLD ANSWER**

You will have to use AJAX.

Javascript alone cannot reach a php script. You will have to make a request, pass the variable to PHP, evaluate it and return a result. If you'are using jQuery sending an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request is fairly simple:

```
$.ajax({
    data: 'orderid=' + your_order_id,
    url: 'url_where_php_is_located.php',
    method: 'POST', // or GET
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

and your php script should get the order id like:

```
echo $_POST['orderid'];
```

The output will return as a string to the success function.

**EDIT**

You can also use the shorthand functions:

```
$.get('target_url', { key: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});

// or eventually $.post instead of $.get
```

Comment: function clickedbutton(buttonid,orderid){
buttonid = "button" + buttonid;
$.ajax({
    data: 'orderid=' + orderid,
    url: 'statusupdate.php',
    method: 'POST', // or GET
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});

}

Comment: $strSQL = "update orders set OrderStatus = 'In Progress' where OrderID = '" + $_POST['buttonid'] + "'";

Answer (score 1):

By using Ajax.

```
function clickedbutton(buttonid,orderid){

    $.post("page.php", { buttonid: buttonid })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });

}
```

In php you get it with $_POST.

```
//[..] previous php code
$strSQL = "update orders set OrderStatus = 'In Progress' where OrderID = '" + $_POST['buttonid'] + "'";
//[..] rest of php code
```

Watch out for SQL injection. Don't take this advice as written.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to use AJAX, you can do something like this in your `clickedbutton` function:

```
window.location.replace('path/to/page.php?orderid=' + orderid);
```

and then in your page.php

```
"...where OrderID = '" . $_GET('orderid') . "'";
```

(note the dots to join strings)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
var url = myurl +'?id=' + orderid;
window.location.href = url;
```

and in php page

```
 $strSQL = "update orders set OrderStatus = 'In Progress' where OrderID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'";
```

**Edit**

If you want to load the php file without page refresh then you can try as fellow friends suggested..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to build a query string and attach it to the end of the php script's url.

```
function clickedbutton(buttonid,orderid){
    var url = 'script.php?';
    var query = 'buttonid=' + buttonid + '&orderid=' + orderid;

    window.location.href = url + query
}
```

In the php script you can access the parameters via like this:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['buttonid'];
echo $_GET['orderid'];
```