# How do I send a variable from a javascript to a php file?

Tags: javascript, php

For example i have a variable

```
var test = "done";
```

how can I send it to php? and then post it

Comment: Submit a form? make an XMLHttpRequest? Make a GET request?

Comment: AJAX is the term you want to Google

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function post and call php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834138/javascript-function-post-and-call-php-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code

```
<script>
 var test = "done";
 document.getElementById('sample').value = test;
</script>

<form method = "post">
   <input type="hidden" id="sample" name="stext">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
 echo $_POST['stext'];
?>
```