# Sending data to table in database with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a js function, in the function body I want to send data to the MySQL database.

I have a video ID and a user ID, and I want to send the video ID (which I already have stored in a var) and the user ID (which I don't have but it's for a different topic.)

This is what I need basically:

```
When something happens//{
Send videoID to database to some table
Send userID to database to some table
}
```

If you guys can help me clear things up a little bit, help me understand how am I supposed to do that, I would be grateful. Thanks! =)

Comment: you can use ajax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to send data to your server and that in turn can update your db

Comment: Like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834138/javascript-function-post-and-call-php-script/16834317